# Using text files to build pages (Rails 2.3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I have some plain text files that I'd like to open and manipulate, then return some output that will be used in the view. I have the name of the file stored in my MySQL database (I would store the text in there but this text can vary drastically in length, making database storage inefficient), but where should I put the files, and what path should I use, to ensure that the server gets a hold of them when I call `File.open()` on it?

And I'd also like to have it so that the users don't have access to the original text files, if at all possible.

All help is appreciated and thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mladen is right. Anywhere outside you public directory is fine. Say you put them in `app/textfiles`. And then — given your text file model is called "TxtFile" and `TxtFile#path => "my_file.txt"`:

```
class TxtFile
  # ...
  def contents
    @contents ||= File.open("#{Rails.root}/app/textfiles/#{path}").read
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Anywhere outside the `public` directory (users can read that), where your web server has read access.